# Centering images on navbar

Tags: html, css, nav

I was trying to do an navbar in css with some icons in it and this is the result:

[image]

And the what I was trying to do was:

[image]

I tried a lot but coudn't get the icons to align with the text, when the images were in the middle the text were on top, when the text were in the middle the images were on the bottom.

**My code:

HTML:**

```
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="left"><a href="#" style="margin-right: 100px;"></a></li>
        <li class="left user_nav"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="left"><a href="#">USERNAME</a></li>
        <li class="left message_nav"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="left settings_nav"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="left"><a href="#">CREDITS</a></li>
        <li class="center logo_nav"><a href="#"></a></li>
         <li class="right"><a href="#" style="margin-left: 100px;"></a></li>
        <li class="right fb_nav"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="right tw_nav"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="right"><a href="#">SEARCH</a></li>
    </ul>
```

The css is a bit too much to post here so I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0roeoeb/) so you can see the full code working.

**Can someone help me to make mine look a bit like the image one?**

Comment: This is a hack solution, but you could go through your elements and add something like this:

position: relative; top: -5px

Comment: Like this: http://codepen.io/mwujek/pen/bVGWjg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save yourself tons of code writing, maintenance and troubleshooting. Use a [**CSS Flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">

    <li id="left-group">
        <ul>
            <li class="user_nav"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">USERNAME</a></li>
            <li class="message_nav"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="settings_nav"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CREDITS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li><!-- end #left-group -->

    <li class="logo_nav"><a href="#"></a></li>

    <li id="right-group">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SEARCH</a></li>
            <li class="fb_nav"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="tw_nav"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li><!-- end #right-group -->

</ul><!-- end .nav -->
```

**CSS** (flex section)

```
ul.nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* this one line vertically centers all nav items */
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 0;
}

li#left-group > ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
}

li#right-group > ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
}

li#left-group { margin-left: 5%; }    
li#right-group { margin-right: 5%; }
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/j0roeoeb/6/

*A few notes:*

- With the flexbox you can achieve your goal with about 50% less code.
- The layout is responsive.
- It's easy to center child elements horizontally or vertically with the [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) and [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) properties.
- [All major browsers support flexbox, except IE 8 & 9.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: Thank you I look so dumb seeing the amount of code you have and works and the amount I have and it don't :/

Comment: Not dumb at all. Flexbox is relatively new. It solves many problems that use to requires much more code. Just read the MDN and CSS-Tricks articles, watch a few YouTube tutorials, and you'll learn how it all works.